# How to access resources from background thread

Tags: android, multithreading, resources

I try to access my string resource from the background thread. How can I do this?

I have the main UI thread where context available of course. And I am tring to implement AsyncTask descendent. In corresponding doInBackground method I have not access to my UI context respectivly. Resources is needed for URL building . I put some path parts into string resource.

Comment: Post what you've tried please.

Comment: You just need a valid context to access resources. Please show your code.

Comment: A context will be enough...

Comment: pass the context as a parameter in AsyncTask constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It  would be better to put your URL building blocks in String constants  in Java so that you avoid the overhead of loading a resource.

Comment: Thank you. I guess it's the best solution.